# PHP Mail does not send code successful

Tags: php, sendmail

I am trying to send mail from contact form but unfortunately I don’t get any mail yet my code runs successfully. It shows that mail is sent but I haven’t received any mail. I don’t know what’s the issue. Does any one know about the solution?? They are welcome.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

ini_set("mail.log", "/tmp/mail.log");
ini_set("mail.add_x_header", TRUE);
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

if(mail('abc@xyz.com', 'My Subject', $message))
{
echo $message." sent successfully";
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the snippet of your code? So we would be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: Try on diffrent email ids,  your email code plz ???

Comment: can you provide your code??

Comment: @PaulCrovella I have gone through it. but it doesn't help. Still I Cant get any mail

Comment: I tried to configure the sendmail but still same problem.

Comment: I am trying on localhost. This is the simple code to check whether the function works or not.

Comment: Is your localhost (XAMPP, WAMP, etc) setup for sending mails?

Comment: @Daenu  Yes I have installed sendmail and postfix.

Comment: hmmm, consider using a library such as PhPmailer. Did you see that answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: Ohk i am trying it. will be back when done. Thanks :)

Comment: Still getting the same errors seems like phpmailer doesnt work. what to do to completely configure postfix??

Comment: @rehmat I have added code in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you. i am also using this code, try this code:

```
$email = 'abc@gmail.com';  
$password = '$email';  
$hash = md5(rand(0,1000));
$to = '$email'; 
$subject = 'Registration | Verification'; 
$message = 'Thanks for signing up! Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.                          
------------------------
    Email: '.$email.'
    Password: '.$password.'
------------------------
Please click this link to activate your account:http://abc.yourdomain.com/register/activate.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.''; 
$headers = 'From:admin@thedigitalmarketingonline.com' . "\r\n"; 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```